# Number of Positive Solutions to a1 x1+a2 x2+......+an xn=k (k<=10^18)

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, dynamic-programming

The question is Number of solutions to a1 x1+a2 x2+....+an xn=k with constraints: 1)ai>0 and ai<=15 2)n>0 and n<=15 3)xi>=0 I was able to formulate a Dynamic programming solution but it is running too long for n>10^10. Please guide me to get a more efficient soution.
The code

```
int dp[]=new int[16];
        dp[0]=1;
        BigInteger seen=new BigInteger("0");
        while(true)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<arr[0];i++)
            {
                if(dp[0]==0)
                    break;
                dp[arr[i+1]]=(dp[arr[i+1]]+dp[0])%1000000007;
            }
            for(int i=1;i<15;i++)
                dp[i-1]=dp[i];
            seen=seen.add(new BigInteger("1"));
            if(seen.compareTo(n)==0)
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(dp[0]);
```

arr is the array containing coefficients and answer should be mod 1000000007 as the number of ways donot fit into an int.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But this optimization in not sufficient as the above code runs O(k) and as k is 10^18.So any optimization on running time will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what `dp[i]` contains, and at what point in the code this is true.

Comment: I remember having seen an exact solution for this problem, but it involves some analysis (Taylor series). I check this as soon as I get home.

Comment: @Serdalis Calculating `n % m` by `n & mask` is possible if and only if `m` is a power of 2, in which case `mask = m-1`.

Comment: @Serdalis That can't be right...

Comment: @DanielFischer, You're correct, I can't believe I forgot that thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for real problem:**

The actual problem is much simpler. However, it's hard to be helpful without spoiling it entirely.

Stripping it down to the bare essentials, the problem is

> Given *k* distinct positive integers *L1*, ... , *Lk* and a nonnegative integer *n*, how many different finite sequences (*a1*, ..., *ar*) are there such that 1. for all *i* (1 <= *i* <= *r*), *ai* is one of the *Lj*, and 2. *a1* + ... + *ar* = *n*. (In other words, the number of *compositions* of *n* using only the given *Lj*.)

For convenience, you are also told that all the *Lj* are <= 15 (and hence *k* <= 15), and *n* <= 10^18. And, so that the entire computation can be carried out using 64-bit integers (the number of sequences grows exponentially with *n*, you wouldn't have enough memory to store the exact number for large *n*), you should only calculate the remainder of the sequence count modulo 1000000007.

To solve such a problem, start by looking at the simplest cases first. The very simplest cases are when only one *L* is given, then evidently there is one admissible sequence if *n* is a multiple of *L* and no admissible sequence if *n* mod *L* != 0. That doesn't help yet. So consider the next simplest cases, two *L* values given. Suppose those are 1 and 2.

1. 0 has one composition, the empty sequence: N(0) = 1
2. 1 has one composition, (1): N(1) = 1
3. 2 has two compositions, (1,1); (2): N(2) = 2
4. 3 has three compositions, (1,1,1);(1,2);(2,1): N(3) = 3
5. 4 has five compositions, (1,1,1,1);(1,1,2);(1,2,1);(2,1,1);(2,2): N(4) = 5
6. 5 has eight compositions, (1,1,1,1,1);(1,1,1,2);(1,1,2,1);(1,2,1,1);(2,1,1,1);(1,2,2);(2,1,2);(2,2,1): N(5) = 8

You may see it now, or need a few more terms, but you'll notice that you get the Fibonacci sequence (shifted by one), N(*n*) = F(*n*+1), thus the sequence N(*n*) satisfies the *recurrence relation*
N(*n*) = N(*n*-1) + N(*n*-2) (for *n* >= 2; we have not yet proved that, so far it's a hypothesis based on pattern-spotting). Now, can we see that without calculating many values? Of course, there are two types of admissible sequences, those ending with 1 and those ending with 2. Since that partitioning of the admissible sequences restricts only the last element, the number of ad. seq. summing to *n* and ending with 1 is N(*n*-1) and the number of ad. seq. summing to *n* and ending with 2 is N(*n*-2).

That reasoning immediately generalises, given *L1* < *L2* < ... < *Lk*, for all *n* >= *Lk*, we have

> N(*n*) = N(*n-L1*) + N(*n-L2*) + ... + N(*n-Lk*)

with the obvious interpretation if we're only interested in N(*n*) % *m*.

Umm, that linear recurrence still leaves calculating N(*n*) as an O(*n*) task?
Yes, but researching a few of the mentioned keywords quickly leads to an algorithm needing only O(log *n*) steps ;)

**Algorithm for misinterpreted problem, no longer relevant, but may still be interesting:**

The question looks a little SPOJish, so I won't give a complete algorithm (at least, not before I've googled around a bit to check if it's a contest question). I hope no restriction has been omitted in the description, such as that permutations of such representations should only contribute one to the count, that would considerably complicate the matter. So I count `1*3 + 2*4 = 11` and `2*4 + 1*3 = 11` as two different solutions.

Some notations first. For m-tuples of numbers, let `< | >` denote the canonical bilinear pairing, i.e.
`<a|x> = a_1*x_1 + ... + a_m*x_m`. For a positive integer B, let `A_B = {1, 2, ..., B}` be the set of positive integers not exceeding B. Let N denote the set of natural numbers, i.e. of nonnegative integers.
For `0 <= m, k` and `B > 0`, let `C(B,m,k) = card { (a,x) \in A_B^m × N^m : <a|x> = k }`.

Your problem is then to find `\sum_{m = 1}^15 C(15,m,k)` (modulo 1000000007).

For completeness, let us mention that `C(B,0,k) = if k == 0 then 1 else 0`, which can be helpful in theoretical considerations. For the case of a positive number of summands, we easily find the recursion formula

```
C(B,m+1,k) = \sum_{j = 0}^k C(B,1,j) * C(B,m,k-j)
```

By induction, `C(B,m,_)` is the convolution¹ of m factors `C(B,1,_)`. Calculating the convolution of two known functions up to `k` is `O(k^2)`, so if `C(B,1,_)` is known, that gives an `O(n*k^2)` algorithm to compute `C(B,m,k), 1 <= m <= n`. Okay for small k, but our galaxy won't live to see you calculating `C(15,15,10^18)` that way. So, can we do better? Well, if you're familiar with the Laplace-transformation, you'll know that an analogous transformation will convert the convolution product to a pointwise product, which is much easier to calculate. However, although the transformation is in this case easy to compute, the inverse is not. Any other idea? Why, yes, let's take a closer look at `C(B,1,_)`.

```
C(B,1,k) = card { a \in A_B : (k/a) is an integer }
```

In other words, `C(B,1,k)` is the number of divisors of `k` not exceeding `B`. Let us denote that by `d_B(k)`. It is immediately clear that `1 <= d_B(k) <= B`. For `B = 2`, evidently `d_2(k) = 1 if k is odd, 2 if k is even`. `d_3(k) = 3` if and only if `k` is divisible by 2 and by 3, hence iff `k` is a multiple of 6, `d_3(k) = 2` if and only if one of 2, 3 divides `k` but not the other, that is, iff `k % 6 \in {2,3,4}` and finally, `d_3(k) = 1` iff neither 2 nor 3 divides k, i.e. iff `gcd(k,6) = 1`, iff `k % 6 \in {1,5}`. So we've seen that `d_2` is periodic with period 2, `d_3` is periodic with period 6. Generally, like reasoning shows that `d_B` is periodic for all B, and the minimal positive period divides `B!`.

Given any positive period P of `C(B,1,_) = d_B`, we can split the sum in the convolution (k = q*P+r, 0 <= r < P):

```
C(B,m+1, q*P+r) = \sum_{c = 0}^{q-1} (\sum_{j = 0}^{P-1} d_B(j)*C(B,m,(q-c)*P + (r-j)))
                + \sum_{j = 0}^r d_B(j)*C(B,m,r-j)
```

The functions `C(B,m,_)` are no longer periodic for `m >= 2`, but there are simple formulae to obtain `C(B,m,q*P+r)` from `C(B,m,r)`. Thus, with `C(B,1,_) = d_B` and `C(B,m,_)` known up to P, calculating `C(B,m+1,_)` up to P is an `O(P^2)` task², getting the data necessary for calculating `C(B,m+1,k)` for arbitrarily large k, needs m such convolutions, hence that's `O(m*P^2)`.

Then finding `C(B,m,k)` for `1 <= m <= n` and arbitrarily large k is `O(n^2*P^2)`, in time and `O(n^2*P)` in space.
For B = 15, we have 15! = 1.307674368 * 10^12, so using that for P isn't feasible. Fortunately, the smallest positive period of `d_15` is *much* smaller, so you get something workable. From a rough estimate, I would still expect the calculation of `C(15,15,k)` to take time more appropriately measured in hours than seconds, but it's an improvement over `O(k)` which would take years (for k in the region of 10^18).

¹ The convolution used here is `(f \ast g)(k) = \sum_{j = 0}^k f(j)*g(k-j)`.
² Assuming all arithmetic operations are O(1); if, as in the OP, only the residue modulo some M > 0 is desired, that holds if all intermediate calculations are done modulo M.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.I very much appreciate your patience in answering my question.But i have to say your solution is complex for me to understand.Also you mentioned that your solution takes hours for k in range 10^18.I am looking for a solution to be completed within 7 sec.

Comment: @DineshReddy [This one](http://www.codechef.com/NOV11/problems/HAREJUMP), I suspect? That's a different problem and faster to solve. If that's the one, I can work out what hints I could give without entirely spoiling the problem.

Comment: Yeah,Thats the problem.Please help me out

Comment: Daniel from Project Euler, is that you?